# How to reprocess a deadlocked action from http request

Tags: c#, sql-server, http, deadlock

The thing is that SQL Server sometimes chooses a session as its deadlock victim when 2 processes lock each other out. The one process does an update and the other just a read. During read SQL Server creates so called 'shared locks' which does not block other reader but does block updaters. So far the only way to solve this is to reprocess the victimized thread.

Now this is happening in a web application and I would like to have a mechanism that can do the reprocessing (let's say with a maximum of 5 times) when needed.

I've looked at the `IHttpModule` which has a `BeginRequest()` and `EndRequest()` event being called (amongst other events) but that does not give me the ability to reprocess the request.

In fact what I need is something that forces itself between the http handler and the process being called.

I could write something like this:

```
int maxtries = 5;

while(maxtries > 0)
{
    try
    {
        using(var scope = Session.OpenTransaction())
        {
            // process

            scope.Complete(); // commit

            return result;
        }
    }
    catch(DeadlockException dlex)
    {
        maxtries--;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

but I would have to write that for all requests which is tedious and error prone. I would be nice if I could just configure a kind of reprocessing handler via the Web.Config that is automatically called and does the processing deadlock reprocessing for me.

Comment: What web tech are you using? WebForms, MVC, Web API?

Comment: I know you want to do it in C#, but you might want to consider re-trying in SQL.  Take a look at this article we found when I was researching a deadlock issue. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42547/SQL-SERVER-How-To-Handle-Deadlock

Comment: We use Microsoft's MVC4

Comment: Using SQL is not an option for us. We use an ORM (DataObjects.Net) for our data access

Comment: DataObjects.Net has a reprocessing library but that more or less does what I've written in my little example code but fancier.

Comment: I could also reissue the request from the client on receiving the deadlock error but that feels not right.

Answer (score 2):

If your getting deadlocks you've got something wrong in your DB layer. You missing indices or something similar, or you are doing out of sequence updates within transactions that are locking dependant entities.

Regardless using HTTP as a mechanism to handle this error is not the way to go. 
If you truly need to retry a deadlock, then you should wrap the attempt in your own function and retry almost exactly as you describe above.

**BUT** I would strongly suggest that you identify the cause of the deadlock and resolve it.

Hope that does not sound too dismissive of your problem, but fix the cause of the problem not the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MVC and assuming it is safe to rerun your entire action on DB failure, you can simply write a common base controller class from which all of your controllers will inherit (if you already don't have one), and in it override `OnActionExecuting` and trap specific exception(s) and retry.  This way you'll have the code only in one place, but, again, assuming it is safe to rerun the entire action in such case.

Example:

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(
    ActionExecutingContext filterContext
        )
    {
        int maxtries = 5;

        while(maxtries > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                return base.OnActionExecuting(filtercontext);
            }
            catch(DeadlockException dlex)
            {
                maxtries--;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Persistent DB locking - max retries reached.");
    }
}
```

... and then simply update every relevant controller to inherit from this controller (again, if you don't already have a common controller).

EDIT: B/w, Bigtoe's answer is correct - deadlock is the cause and should be dealt with accordingly.  The above solution is really a workaround if DB layer cannot be reliably fixed.  The first attempt should be on reviewing and (re-)structuring queries so as to avoid deadlock in the first place. Only if that is not practical should the above workaround be employed.